# What can I do to fix an error inside of case?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, debian

My code is:

```
-cname)
    changeName="{2}"

    if [ -z $changeName ]; then
        echo -en "Which note name do you want to change?"
        read -r $changeName
        echo "What would you like to change the name to?"
        read -r changeNewName
    if ! [ -z "${3}" ]; then
        echo "The name has to have no spaces."
        exit 1
    fi          
    if [ -f /usr/share/cnote/notes/$changeNewName ]; then
        echo "That note name is already used. Please choose a new one."
        exit 1
    fi
    cp "/usr/share/cnote/notes/${changeName}" "/usr/share/cnote/notes/${changeNewName}"
    ;;
```

If I remove this part of my case statement it works again but with that part I get that error: 
root@minibian:~/cnote# ./cnote -cname
./cnote: line 73: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
./cnote: line 73:`             ;;'

Comment: You are missing a `fi`, presumably immediately after `read -r changeNewName`.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is quite useful in such cases

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` block is not closed. and you should not put the $ symbol ahead of changeName. So the first part must be

```
if [ -z $changeName ]; then
    echo -en "Which note name do you want to change?"
    read -r changeName
    echo "What would you like to change the name to?"
    read -r changeNewName
fi
```